# Warning "Automatic reindexing" when applying IQR on the Pandas Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science, sklearn-pandas

When I try to remove outliers from my dataset, I get this warning:

**Code**

```py
def remout(df):
    Q1 = df.quantile(0.02)
    Q3 = df.quantile(0.98)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    df = df[~((df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]
    return df

df=remout(df)
df
```

**Warning Message**

```
FutureWarning: Automatic reindexing on DataFrame vs Series comparisons is deprecated and will raise ValueError in a future version. Do `left, right = left.align(right, axis=1, copy=False)` before e.g. `left == right`
  df = df[~((df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: It's not an error, but a warning.  Did you still get the results you expected?  A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help, as we don't know anything about the contents of your dataframe.  Also, include your pandas version.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not specifying which column you're targeting to omit your outliers from, if your dataframe has one column, fine, but generally speaking you have to give a dataframe and a single column as an input to this function.

Second, Interquartile score or IQR is defined as difference between the 75th percentile and the 25th percentile. Therefore the numbers you have introduced as Q1 and Q3 are wrong.

Third, there is a problem with the logic you have used in your function, this will solve the problem without any future warnings:

```py
def remout(df, col):
    Q1 = df[col].quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = df[col].quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    print(Q1, Q3, IQR)
    df = df[(df[col] > (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) & (df[col] < (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))]
    return df

df=remout(df, 'col_name')
```

Instead of `col_name` specify the name of the column you want to remove outliers from.